# How to solve CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806) and NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios5

Has anyone with the iOS 9  had this issue?

I use standard NSURLSession and  NSURLSessionDataTask to connect to a webservice and as soon as a call is made to the webservice i get the below error in my log.

1) CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
2) NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
 // response code here
}

And my info.plist is look like

[image]

Comment: My url request to Server will be like  [ https:// 128.199.104.107:443/login ]

Comment: NSAllowsArbitraryLoads should be set to true

Comment: i changed it to true but i would not work

Comment: What does your URL look like? I mean http:// or https://? Try with https://

Comment: i tried with https:// only @varun

Comment: @Varun did you ever find a resolution to this?

Comment: @billy_comic No. I guess one possible solution to this would be to remove everything under exception domains and set the allows arbitrary loads to true.